# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el Id de una tabla durante una transacción?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

estoy realizando una transacción en mi controlador. Los primeros datos que ingreso van a la tabla "Empresas" en mi base de datos, y cuando realizo el `.Add()`, la base de datos le asigna un Id automáticamente gracias al Identity Specification.

Para realizar el segundo registro, necesito usar ese Id creado para insertarlo dentro de mi otra tabla. Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
 using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = Datos.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Empresas empresa = new Empresas()
                            {
                                Nombre = empresasObj.Nombre,
                                DireccionWeb = empresasObj.DireccionWeb,

                            };

                            Datos.Empresas.Add(empresa);
                            Datos.SaveChanges();

                            EmpresasModulos empresasModulos{
                            EmpresaId = ¿?; //Acá necesito el Id
                            };

                            dbTran.Commit();
                            
                            RemoveDatos();
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");                            
                        }
}
```

Ingreso los datos en la tabla "Empresas", su Nombre y su dirección Web, y la base de datos le asigna un Id en forma de entero o `int`, y luego en la segunda tabla necesito recuperar ese Id creado.

Estoy Usando Entity Framework y Linq.

Comment: Ya revisaste el objeto `empresa`? Una vez que se hace `SaveChanges()`, Entity Framework asigna el Id generado en la base de datos cuando la columna es `IDENTITY`. Estblece un punto de interrupción luego del `SaveChanges()` y revisa la propiedad `empresa.Id`. Es probable que EF ya haya rellenado ese campo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice el compañero en los comentarios, Entity Framework retorna el **Id**
después de guardar los cambios **SaveChanges()**, entonces para obtenerlo siguiendo la estructura de tu códio sería así

```
using (DbContextTransaction dbTran = Datos.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
      try
      {
           Empresas empresa = new Empresas()
          {
             Nombre = empresasObj.Nombre,
             DireccionWeb = empresasObj.DireccionWeb,
          };

          Datos.Empresas.Add(empresa);
          Datos.SaveChanges();

          EmpresasModulos empresasModulos{
          EmpresaId = empresa.Id; //Así obtienes el Id insertado
                        

          dbTran.Commit();
                        
          RemoveDatos();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");                            
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando **Linq** obtienes el último registro insertado en la tabla con el **método LastOrDeFault**:

```
var empresa = datos.Empresas.LastOrDefault();
```

Una vez que obtienes el último registro ya puedes acceder a cualquier propiedad del mismo.

```
otroObjeto.Id = empresa.Id;
```

Para poder usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```